# Use mapply for multiple vectors but only once for each element

Tags: r, mapply

I try to iterate over multiple vectors like Pythons "for x, y, z in zip(lia, lib, lic): ..." and found `mapply` which does what I want, but it returns too much.

Example:

```
lia = c(1,2,3)
lib = c(4,5,6)
lic = c(7,8,9)
mapply(function(x, y, z) print(sprintf('%f %f %f', x, y, z)), lia, lib, lic )
```

Results in:

```
[1] "1.000000 4.000000 7.000000"
[1] "2.000000 5.000000 8.000000"
[1] "3.000000 6.000000 9.000000"
[[1]]
[1] "1.000000 4.000000 7.000000"

[[2]]
[1] "2.000000 5.000000 8.000000"

[[3]]
[1] "3.000000 6.000000 9.000000"
```

The first three lines are what I expect. Why it is returning more?
How would I do it correctly?

Comment: `print` is overkill, try without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `print`,  `mapply` still has it's own output which you may make `invisible`. However, maybe you don't need `print` at all.

Try one of the two:

```
invisible(mapply(function(x, y, z) print(sprintf('%f %f %f', x, y, z)), lia, lib, lic))
# [1] "1.000000 4.000000 7.000000"
# [1] "2.000000 5.000000 8.000000"
# [1] "3.000000 6.000000 9.000000"

mapply(function(x, y, z) sprintf('%f %f %f', x, y, z), lia, lib, lic)
# [1] "1.000000 4.000000 7.000000" "2.000000 5.000000 8.000000" "3.000000 6.000000 9.000000"
```

Comment: Thank you! My problem was more complex, but with your help I found out that my input was wrong. For a data.frame "df" I have to use: df$some_name or df[['some_name']] to create my input vectors. df['some_name'] was not failing, but giving me a matrix output with different combinations.

Comment: Maybe you'll find `?with` useful.